# Webcam recording

Tags: webcam

There is a proposal to install IP cameras in our building to augment an existing set of CCTV cameras. The existing cameras are recorded.  Can anyone suggest a way of recording the output of the IP cameras please.

Also, do people have thoughts on whether installing such cameras is actually useful or even a good idea, e.g. from a security or privacy perspective.  I know nothing of IP cameras but I'm nervous about having publicly available cameras.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to record from an IP camera.  I own one that I use for security purposes, so, I think they are well worth the purchase.  If, for nothing else, it’s nice to have a record of what transpired should I ever need to have one, and, they provide a sense of protection.  As for a solution, I chose to record my IP video to a Synology NAS (Network Attached Storage).  The NAS can be configured with multiple disk drives depending upon your needs.  It comes with several available (and free) software products to enhance the usage of the NAS.  I use [Surveillance Station](https://www.synology.com/en-us/surveillance/6.3) to save the video.  Additionally, Synology also makes available an Android app to view the camera from smartphones.  Lastly, I’m not sure what you meant by "publicly available cameras" since IP cameras, and, in my case, the NAS, are typically password protected.  For the most, part, they are secure from prying eyes.

Comment: By public, I meant that it is on the public internet, not an intranet. Internet devices typically have very little attention to security. Depends upon the model of course...